# Handling HTML form submission

Tags: 7

I am trying to update a node after a form submission with the following code, but it is being run twice:

```
if(isset($params['commit'])){
  $node = node_load($params['commit']);
  $field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_commits'));
  $field_collection_item->setHostEntity('node', $node);
  $fc_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $field_collection_item);
  $fc_wrapper->field_email->set($email);
  $fc_wrapper->save(TRUE);
  $commits = $node->field_commitments['und'][0]['value'];
  $commits = intval($commits);
  $commits = $commits+1;
  $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $node_wrapper->field_commitments->set($commits);
  $node_wrapper->save();

  header('Location: /take-action');
}
```

I am using a standard HTML form with `method="post"` and `action="?commit=[NID]"` because the markup is already given and trying to convert it to work with drupal_get_form and all that is not feasible. Then I'm processing the parameters within the callback's template.

Can anyone give me any idea why the `save()` methods above are called twice? e.g. I submit a single email string, and it gets added twice and so on.

Thank you.

Comment: not had time to test, but you have given the $node to the field_collection_item and then saved, does this therefore save to the parent node? If so you then call save on the node wrapper also.

Comment: actually, just noticed that you have $skip_host_save set to TRUE

Comment: @autopoietic Yeah, even taking that out and just calling `$node_wrapper->save();` or `node_save($node)` has the same issue.